# Qt Creator Application Crashing Issue

Tags: qt, mingw, qt-creator

I am experiencing an issue in Qt Creator. Every Qt application I create seems to have a problem. When I try to run these applications, I encounter the following error:
Starting C:\Users\User1\Documents\build-untitled17-Desktop_Qt_6_6_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\untitled17.exe...
C:\Users\Amirali\User1\build-untitled17-Desktop_Qt_6_6_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\untitled17.exe crashed.

I am using Windows 10, CMake, and Qt 6.6.2 with Qt 6.6.2 (MinGW 11.2.0 64-bit). I have already tried reinstalling Qt, Visual Studio 2022 (MSVC), and MinGW. Even creating a new project like a Qt Widget Application without making any changes still results in a crash. I have also tried both release and debug modes, but it either shows a crash or nothing at all. Please assist me in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Try to start the application not through Qt Creator but by double-clicking the .exe file in Windows explorer. Could be some dll files are missing and when you double-click on the .exe, Windows will notify you what is missing. If that is the case, copy the needed .dll files from your Qt installation to next to your .exe. By default, the Qt installation should be in a path something like C:\Qt\6.5.0\msvc2019_64\bin but that depends on the Qt version.